# Get String value failed from JSON object If Identifier has a blank space android

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

Dears.

I am able to retrieve a JSON object from Alpha Vantage to use in my currency converter application but I am unable to look up for the string value I want (i.e "5. Exchange Rate": "17.86300000") because the identifier has spaces as below:

> {
>       "Realtime Currency Exchange Rate": {
>           "1. From_Currency Code": "USD",
>           "2. From_Currency Name": "United States Dollar",
>           "3. To_Currency Code": "EGP",
>           "4. To_Currency Name": "Egyptian Pound",
>           "5. Exchange Rate": "17.86300000",
>           "6. Last Refreshed": "2017-12-24 14:38:20",
>           "7. Time Zone": "UTC"
>       } }

and hereunder my code to capture the string value

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {



        String urlStr = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency="
                + textto.getText()
                + "&to_currency="
                + textfrom.getText()
                + "&apikey=XXXXXXXXX";

        String data="";
        String converted="";

        try {

            URL url = new URL(urlStr);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line ="";
            while (line != null)
            {
                line=bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data +line;
            }

            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(data);


                JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(0);
                converted = JO.getString("5. Exchange Rate");


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return converted;
    }
```

The method return blank value with no exceptions in logcat. I have tested the code with another JSON object with no spaces in identifier and works well.

Any help what I am missing here?

[image: Update: this is what i get in the data as requested]

Comment: can you post your whole response json

Comment: If the JSON string you show in you post is representative of what you get then I do not see the array. In other words  `JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(data);` should not work. Please show us an example of the JSON string you receive in "data".

Comment: I have updated the question getting the value I get in "data"

Comment: Also this is a URL i get the JSON : https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=USD&to_currency=EGP&apikey=2SDZ5OHC1UFWDTLH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no array in you response json 
instead try this :

```
  JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(data);
  JSONObject sys  = reader.getJSONObject("Realtime Currency Exchange Rate");
  String currency = sys.getString("5. Exchange Rate");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code

```
 JSONObject JA = new JSONObject(data);
 JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.getJSONObject("Realtime Currency Exchange Rate");
 converted = JO.getString("5. Exchange Rate");
```